# What is this three-pronged, ridged tool?

Tags: tools

[image]

Found this tool while cleaning out my uncle's garage.  It's a cast metal fork with three heavily-ridged tines about four inches long, with a crossbar between them about an inch back from the end, and an unpainted wooden handle.  It has absolutely no markings on it.  Nobody remembers where it came from.

Guesses so far include "raccoon prod", "spaghetti server", and "three-pronged blivet".  Any ideas?

Comment: Something to do with cement/conconcrete.

Comment: Get a picture on a white background with no shadows and you can try a google images or bing images search.  (Or I can, but this photo won't work.)

Comment: That's definitely a Farvull Valve installer, they are very hard to install, on the other hand, it might be a muffler bearing installation tool. OK OK, just funning with you all on a bored Thursday morning. Enjoy.   If the moderators want to delete this comment, feel free to, I won't be offended!  But in the meantime enjoy during these tough times.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  maybe the metal part is the handle and the wooden part goes....

Comment: I wonder if the guy who made it thought "500 years from now some archeologist is gonna have a really bad day with this one."

Comment: If you have no luck here, consider the reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/ and don't be surprised to get an accurate answer within minutes to a few hours. Okay, be surprised.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  You have a sick mind, I love it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That my friend is an antique from the 1800's!
[ANTIQUE ME HUNT TRIDENT MEAT TENDERIZER MID 1800'S](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/antique-hunt-trident-meat-tenderizer-1810716218)

Google Lens is a great tool to have.

Comment: Well done!  (see what I did there?)

Comment: @statueuphemism  Google Images (search for antique meat tenderizer) shows same object at some cooking sites,  eBay sales,...   so it looks legit

Comment: [U.S. Patent #613572](https://patents.google.com/patent/US613572).  Granted in 1898, so late 1800s, not mid 1800s.